# New Java applet plugin not being used?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start, next-generation-plugin

I am deploying a signed & trusted applet. We need to run the applet in a separate JVM & increase the heap size. Setting `separate_jvm` & `java_arguments` works on our local boxes. Curiously we have clients that though they are using 1.6.0_15 don't seem to be running the new plugin architecture.

When I check their Java config, "use next-generation plugin" is checked & IE7's option "use Java 1.6.0_15 for applet plugin" is also checked. Nothing seems obviously wrong. The Java console also reports the correct version, but neither `separate_jvm` nor `java_arguments` are respected.

Just as a sanity check we wrapped the applet in a JNLP & set up our web page to serve the applet with a `jnlp_href`. The applet tag had a bogus code parameter to ensure the JVM was actually running the JNLP. The Java console complains that it cannot find the bogus class when it should be properly loading the JNLP.

Are there security settings or something else that might cause what I'm seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I've just a few suggestions rather than an absolute answer.

1. The Java virtual machine version
   and plug in version can be
   different. Go to Control Panel,
   Java, Runtime Environment settings.
   When you check the console it may
   show the two different versions.
2. The new plugin architecture would
   depend on browser, Opera doesn't use
   it at all, for example. IE7 does
   though. So check which browser it
   works on.
3. Java has got corrupted due to
   repeated installs and uninstalls.
   Pretty common complaint I've found.
   If you have control over one of the
   machines you should uninstall every
   Java. Restart machine. Install
   latest Java.

Comment: 1. I checked the Control Panel, Java, Runtime Environment & /Program Files/Java. Only 1.6.0_15 exists.

2. Right. We're definitely using IE7 - which is where I've seen it work on my dev box.

3. That is possible. I'll have to check that.

Comment: We reinstalled the JVM without luck. It's still running the old version.

Comment: The old version of the plugin that is. The JVM appears to be the correct version.

Comment: Hmmm, could you try a different browser on the same machine to isolate whether it's IE7 specific?

Comment: I really don't have that luxury. The machines are pretty locked down.

Comment: I think this turned out to be a weird bug/change introduced in u17. Thanks for the help.